# javax.validation.constraints with custom Code and Message

Tags: java, javax.validation

I am using the `javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty` library to validate POJO class for rest request. Within class i have used below annotaion.

```
@ApiModelProperty(value = "Name", required = true)
@NotEmpty(message = "Name is required")
private String name;
```

Above code is working fine and returning the response as below when name is empty

```
 "code": "NotEmpty",
 "message": "Name is required"
```

Is there any way through which i can display/provide the my own Custom code value instead of  `"code": "NotEmpty"`. Something like  `"code": "INVALID NAME"`.

Any approach suggestion on this must be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to implement your own exception handler and build the entire response as you need to it, as simple text, JSON, XML, etc..

```
@ControllerAdvice
class ExceptionAdvisor {
    @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
    ResponseEntity<MyErrorType> handleTypeMismatchException(ValidationException ex) {
        /*process all the constraint violations*/
        MyErrorType result = . . .;
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(result);
    }
}
```

There is also the Payload option:

```
public static class NameInvalid implements Payload {}
.
.
.
@NotEmpty(message = "Name is required", payload = NameInvalid.class)
private String name;
```

Which should get you this:

```
"code": "NameInvalid",
"message": "Name is required"
```

Comment: Is there way to use the custom code values in the @NotEmpty

Comment: I updated the answer to show you how to use the annotation's payload parameter.